# Parse error in code syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php

```
$arg1 = $row1['asd'];
$arg2 = $row2['asd'];
$f1 = $row1['asd'] + 65 * float atan(float $arg1);
$f2 = $row2['asd'] + 65 * float atan(float $arg2);
```

I'm fairly new to PHP, I think I missed a few quotes so any correction would be very appreciated!

Comment: `float atan(float $arg1)` --- what does it mean?

Comment: if you are casting with `float` wrap them in parentheses.

Comment: Seems like you have copied the function description from the php manual. I suggest you to get more familiar with the PHP manual, eg how to read it correctly.

Comment: I'm guessing you've misunderstood the documentation's [method synopsis](http://uk.php.net/atan#refsect1-function.atan-description). The appearance of `float` in this is to highlight to you the function's parameters and return types.

Comment: Just figured that out haha, thank you guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `float`'s

```
$f1 = $row1['asd'] + 65 * atan($arg1);
$f2 = $row2['asd'] + 65 * atan($arg2);
```

You've probably picked part of this code from the [PHP documentation of this function](http://php.net/atan), right?

If yes, the term before the function name is the type it returns, and the term before the argument is the type of data it expects as argument.

If you want to cast your values to `float` before passing them to `atan`, you can use the [`floatval`](http://php.net/floatval) function.